# Is it safe to carry black soul gems?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, I came across the book [Souls, Black and White](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Souls,_Black_and_White). This book ends with the following passage:

> Even if one were to ignore the guild strictures against the necromantic arts used to power black soul gems, it is dangerous to the caster to handle them for long. If the gem is not precisely the size of the encased soul, small bits of the caster's soul may leak into the gem when it is touched.

Is this true? Is there any danger to carrying around or using black soul gems? I have had three on me for a while and I don't think anything bad has happened to me as a result...

Comment: I've never had anything bad happen to my characters carrying black soul gems (at least not from the gems).  I've carried both full and empty of all sizes for long periods of time.  My bet is that is just the book telling a story that does not cross over into actual game-play.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no actual danger in carrying black soul gems in the game. Although the dangers of black soul gems lore-wise has been evident for some time now, it's never been implemented into any of the games.